# How to connect with my Database using UcanAccess and iReport in netbeans?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport, ucanaccess

I downloaded the Jasper Report plugin for netbeans 8 to practice and make some reports for my program, but I dont understand how I have to type the JDBC URL. I already add the driver of UcanAccess following [the tutorial](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) of the oficial web site.

I'm stuck at this part:

[image]
[image]

is first time that I attempt this with JAVA and I'm not understanding honestly how I have to write the address of my db files. (Greatly appreciate it if possible, give me a link to a tutorial, if it exists.)

Comment: Open a datasource properties and write there.

Comment: Did you add the "UcanAcess DB" entry yourself, or was it pre-installed for you? In either case it's wrong because you'll need to use the UCanAccess driver itself, not the HSQLDB driver. (UCanAccess uses HSQLDB internally, but that is beside the point.) The URL also needs to be of the form `jdbc:ucanaccess://[path_to_database_file]`.

Comment: By the way, [this page](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/ireport-designer) says that iReport Designer is no longer supported (as of 2015-12-31) and has been replaced by [Jaspersoft Studio](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio).

Comment: well... then seeing that source, I think it would be better to download the Jaspersoft Studio ...